# How do I add setTimeout to this type animation?

Tags: javascript

I'm no javascripter. I know enough to copy, paste, and tinker. But I can't make enough sense of this script to add a setTimeout, going off of the W3 example.

Here's the script I'm using for a text type animation. I'd like to delay the function by a few ms. How can I go about doing that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 8) || 200;
    this.txt = '';
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
    var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    if (this.isDeleting) {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 2.5);
    } else {
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    }

    this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

    var that = this;
    var delta = 122 - Math.random() * 110;

    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
    delta = this.period;
    this.isDeleting = true;
    } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
    this.isDeleting = false;
    this.loopNum++;
    delta = 900;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
    for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        if (toRotate) {
          new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

Comment: setTimeout(function() {
    that.tick();
    }, delta); 
your delta variable is the part that sets the the 900 ms, if you change that to 10000 = 10 seconds

Comment: That delta value is the time elapsed between typing/deleting each character apparently.

Answer (score 1):

To delay a function with `setTimeout`, you need to do something like this:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    // awesome stuff
};

setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
```

This will run `myFunction` after 1000ms have elapsed.

You can also define the function you want to delay anonymously as the first argument to `setTimeout` like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // awesome stuff
}, 1000);
```

These two versions of using `setTimeout` are identicle.